# iTextPdf and iTextSharp - Malformed PDF causes hang

Tags: pdf, itext

I recently received a PDF which causes the application to hang when loading in both iText Java and iTextSharp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that the PDF had incremental updates and the additional trailer had a Prev entry pointing to its own cross-reference table. This causes an infinite loop in `PdfReader.ReadXref()`.

My proposed solution is as follows.

```
while (true) {
    PdfNumber prev = (PdfNumber)trailer2.Get(PdfName.PREV);
    if (prev == null)
        break;
    // Add check to prevent infinite loop
    if (prev.LongValue == startxref)
        throw new InvalidPdfException("trailer Prev points to its own cross-reference section.");
    // end added check
    tokens.Seek(prev.LongValue);
    trailer2 = ReadXrefSection();
}
```

Apologies to StackOverflow for this not actually being a question, but I can't afford the time to satisfy the iText requirements for a pull request for two lines of code.

Comment: Thank you! We haven't seen a PDF of which the `/Prev` refers to the actual `xref` before (it wonder which tool made that PDF), but we'll add this extra check to make iText more robust when encountering bad PDFs.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie It was created by InDesign and modified with iText 5.4.3, probably by DotLoop. (has DotLoop signatures anyway). I'd be happy to send it to you if you're interested.

Comment: No need to apologise. I answer my own questions all the time. I seem to find my answers 10minutes after asking someone (friend, SO)... This is usually after hours and hours of research/work trying to solve alone.